# Delivery in a SalesForce environment

Tags: continuous-delivery

In an organization with a hundred developers, and several thousand salespeople using SalesForce to create their application. Given the restrictions of SalesForce environment and deployment options.

What would be the process and which tools to use to reach a delivery pipeline where changes can be delivered to production many times per day?

The basic flow is:

1. salespeople think of ideas for improving their flow (bugs, new dev).
2. product managers distill the requirements and pass onto developers.
3. developers write code and create configuration changes in git.
4. magic happens (currently takes about 3-4 months).
5. new changes are in production and salespeople can use it.

Comment: SalesForce offers afaik a complex mix of products. For a use case, you could list the tools and check for APIs available.

Comment: The list of APIs at https://developer.salesforce.com/ is even larger, and most of these do not support continuous delivery really. Would be interested in learning from practical experience of developers working with the SF platform now they can shorten lead time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create an issue about CD in the ticket system of salesforce. I have googled a little bit and this seems to be [their issue tracker](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index).

I would prevent to implement CD in salesforce as that will be very cumbersome and will take a lot of time. In my opinion this issue should be solved by SalesForce itself.